# Assign column value if index contains substring that matches the index of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, bioinformatics

I have a list of adata objects `dfs` derived from `scanpy`, which uses Pandas under the hood. Its observations can be obtained, for example, using `dfs["GSM4819737"].obs`.

If the index of the observations match the substring of `anno.index` after the last `_` delimiter, assign the `label` column from `anno.index` to the corresponding row in the observations table.

If there are no matches (i.e., un-annotated), remove the row.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import scanpy as sc

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_path):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith("_ccRCC.h5"):
            file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)  # Get the full file path
            id = file.split("_")[0]
            dfs[id] = sc.read_10x_h5(file_path, genome="GRCh38", backup_url=None)    
            dfs[id].var_names_make_unique()
            results_file[id] = id + ".h5ad"


for i in dfs:
    ids = anno.index.str.extract(r'([^_]*)$')[0].tolist()
    if any(j in dfs[i].obs.index.map(str).tolist() for j in ids):
        for k in ids:
            dfs[i].obs = dfs[i].obs.join(anno.set_index(k)).dropna()
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------


    KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [124], in <cell line: 1>()
          3 if any(j in dfs[i].obs.index.map(str).tolist() for j in ids):
          4     for k in ids:
    ----> 5         dfs[i].obs = dfs[i].obs.join(anno.set_index(k)).dropna()
    
    File ~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:5859, in DataFrame.set_index(self, keys, drop, append, inplace, verify_integrity)
       5856                 missing.append(col)
       5858 if missing:
    -> 5859     raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
       5861 if inplace:
       5862     frame = self
    
    KeyError: "None of ['AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1'] are in the columns"
```

Input:

`dfs`

```
{'GSM4819737': AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 1916 × 2252
     obs: 'n_genes', 'n_genes_by_counts', 'total_counts', 'total_counts_mt', 'pct_counts_mt', 'leiden'
     var: 'gene_ids', 'n_cells', 'mt', 'n_cells_by_counts', 'mean_counts', 'pct_dropout_by_counts', 'total_counts', 'highly_variable', 'means', 'dispersions', 'dispersions_norm', 'mean', 'std'
     uns: 'hvg', 'leiden', 'leiden_colors', 'leiden_sizes', 'log1p', 'neighbors', 'paga', 'pca', 'rank_genes_groups', 'umap'
     obsm: 'X_pca', 'X_umap'
     varm: 'PCs'
     obsp: 'connectivities', 'distances',
 'GSM4819735': AnnData object with n_obs × n_vars = 713 × 2619
     obs: 'n_genes', 'n_genes_by_counts', 'total_counts', 'total_counts_mt', 'pct_counts_mt', 'leiden'
     var: 'gene_ids', 'n_cells', 'mt', 'n_cells_by_counts', 'mean_counts', 'pct_dropout_by_counts', 'total_counts', 'highly_variable', 'means', 'dispersions', 'dispersions_norm', 'mean', 'std'
     uns: 'hvg', 'leiden', 'leiden_colors', 'leiden_sizes', 'log1p', 'neighbors', 'paga', 'pca', 'rank_genes_groups', 'umap'
     obsm: 'X_pca', 'X_umap'
     varm: 'PCs'
     obsp: 'connectivities', 'distances'}
```

`dfs["GSM4819737"].obs.iloc[0:2,:]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'n_genes': {'AAACCTGGTAAATGTG-1': 2261, 'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 2497},
 'n_genes_by_counts': {'AAACCTGGTAAATGTG-1': 2261, 'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 2497},
 'total_counts': {'AAACCTGGTAAATGTG-1': 5744.0, 'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 10502.0},
 'total_counts_mt': {'AAACCTGGTAAATGTG-1': 146.0, 'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 18.0},
 'pct_counts_mt': {'AAACCTGGTAAATGTG-1': 2.5417826175689697,
  'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 0.1713959276676178},
 'leiden': {'AAACCTGGTAAATGTG-1': '2', 'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': '1'}})
```

`anno.head().iloc[0:2,-2:]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'label': {'SI_18854_AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': '1:Tumor',
  'SI_18854_AAACCTGTCCACTGGG-1': '1:Tumor'},
 'patient': {'SI_18854_AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 'SS_2005',
  'SI_18854_AAACCTGTCCACTGGG-1': 'SS_2005'}})
```

Desired output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'n_genes': {'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 2497},
 'n_genes_by_counts': {'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 2497},
 'total_counts': {'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 10502.0},
 'total_counts_mt': {'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 18.0},
 'pct_counts_mt': {'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': 0.1713959276676178},
 'leiden': {'AAACCTGCAAGTAGTA-1': '1'}
 'label': {'1:Tumor'}})
```

Comment: If you consider `dfs["GSM4819737"].obs.iloc[0:2,:]` as `df1`, and `anno.head().iloc[0:2,-2:]` as `df2`, then `df1.join(df2.set_index(df2.index.str.extract(r'([^_]*)$')[0])).dropna()` will give you your desired result (subject to dropping the `patient` column)

Comment: @Nick, I tried your code but it threw another error. Please refer to the edited question. Thanks

Comment: I was thinking something more like this: https://ideone.com/NomTCh This is about as good as I can do without access to a more complete dataset

Comment: could you simplify your question to be reproductible. I think thee is no use of scanpy for the sample code. Also, give a simple way to initialize data.